# Loading a huge Keras Model into a Flask App

Tags: python, flask, keras

I'm building a small Flask app that uses a convolutional neural net behind the scenes to make predictions on user uploaded images. It works if I load it like this:

```
@app.route("/uploader", methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        sfname = 'static/'+str(secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(sfname)
        clf = catdog.classifier()
        return render_template('result.html', pred = clf.predict(sfname), imgpath = sfname)
```

However, this requires the the classifier (clf) be loaded after the user adds the image. This takes a while, as it requires setting up all weights for a 200+ layer neural network from a pickle file.

What I want to do is load all the weights when the app is spawned. To do this, I've tried this (cutting out unrelated code for HTML templates/imports/app launch):

```
# put model into memory on spawn
clf = catdog.classifier()
# Initialize the app
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/uploader", methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        sfname = 'static/'+str(secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(sfname)
        return render_template('result.html', pred = clf.predict(sfname), imgpath = sfname)
```

When I do this, I get this traceback (skipping all the flask specific traces at the top):

```
 File "/Users/zachariahmiller/Documents/Metis/test_area/flask_catdog/flask_backend.py", line 26, in get_image
    return render_template('result.html', pred = clf.predict(sfname), imgpath = sfname)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/Documents/Metis/test_area/flask_catdog/catdog.py", line 56, in predict
    prediction = self.model.predict(img_to_predict, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1569, in predict
    self._make_predict_function()
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1037, in _make_predict_function
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2095, in function
    return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2049, in __init__
    with tf.control_dependencies(self.outputs):
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3583, in control_dependencies
    return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3314, in control_dependencies
    c = self.as_graph_element(c)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2405, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/Users/zachariahmiller/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2484, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I'm not sure why loading the classifier outside of the specific call as a global object to the app makes it fail. It should be in memory, and I've seen other examples of folks doing this with SKLearn Classifiers. Any ideas on why this causes this error?

Comment: Looks like some threading issue to me. Googling shows up several similar issues when working with Keras on Tensorflow and Flask. One solution seems to be explicitly working on the correct graph: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#get_default_graph

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `debug=False` in flask.

Worked for me after many failed tensorflow saving/loading attempts.

(thanks to shafy @github)
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2397#issuecomment-338659190

for me, it looks like this, at the bottom of my flask app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Comment: I had to do `app.run(debug=False, threaded=False)`.  Mostly I like python, but sometimes the error messaging is no help.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I had the same problem.

I was running my python server as threaded=True. Removing this, lets mine work

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
```

---->

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Debug didn't seem to affect anything for me

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was stuck here, in mycase i had to explicitly define threaded = False.