# Keras load_model() fails in Flask request context only

Tags: python, flask, keras

I have a working Keras model that makes predictions great in the repl but fails to load in a Flask app. Is this a Keras bug or am I missing some basic Python variable scope understanding?

The Flask app:

```
# app.py

import os
import sys
from train import train_model
from predict import predict_image
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return jsonify({'status': 'Service available.'}), 200

@app.route('/predict') # ?company=<company_id>&image_url=<image_url>
def predict_route():
    company_id = request.args.get('company')
    image_url = str(request.args.get('image_url'))
    result = predict_image(company_id, url=image_url)
    return jsonify(result), 200
```

And my prediction module:

```
# predict.py

import os
import random
import re
import pickle
import utils
import shutil
import requests
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K


def load_classification_model(company_id):
    model_dir = os.path.realpath('./models/company_' + str(company_id))
    model_dir += '/' + os.listdir(model_dir)[-1]
    model_path = model_dir + '/model.h5'
    labels_path = model_dir + '/labels.pickle'
    print 'Loading model ' + model_path + ' ...'
    model = load_model(model_path)
    graph = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[-1].output])
    class_names = pickle.load(open(labels_path, 'rb'))
    return graph, class_names


def predict_image(company_id, url = None, part = None, inspection = None):    
    model_graph, class_names = load_classification_model(company_id)
    # ...etc...
```

It WORKS via repl:

```
import predict
predict.predict_image(...)
# model loads and returns expected result
```

But if I try it via the Flask app I get

```
# curl ml:5000/predict?company=1&image_url=<image_url>

[top of traceback omitted for brevity]
  File "/code/app.py", line 22, in predict_route
    result = predict_image(company_id, url=image_url)
  File "/code/predict.py", line 34, in predict_image
    model_graph, class_names = load_classification_model(company_id)
  File "/code/predict.py", line 21, in load_classification_model
    model = load_model(model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 242, in load_model
    topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 3095, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2193, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1071, in _run
    + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(2048, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Comment: What do you pass to `predict.predict_image(...)` in REPL?

Comment: Identical arguments as are passed in with Flask, I've printed them to check. The error traceback indicates a different type of problem also, so I think that's unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a bug in Keras when using tensorflow graph cross threads. To fix it:

```
    # Right after loading or constructing your model, save the TensorFlow graph:
    import tensorflow as tf
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    # In the other thread (or perhaps in an asynchronous event handler), do:
    global graph
    with graph.as_default():
        (...
        do
        inference
        here...)
```

Comment: Appreciate your input. In Flask, I'm not able to even load the graph, so I'm not able to get the default graph from tf after loading. This seemed plausible and may be on the right track, but I feel like it's more related to Keras loading the model from it's saved model format, and that happening differently in Flask than REPL.

Comment: I think you should better load the Keras model when you initialize the Flask `app` instead of loading the model again and again when the API is called, it will be very slow. If you load the model in this way, you can get the graph, and when the API is called, you just need to use the initialized model to predict and wrap it with `with graph.as_default():
`

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `debug=False` in flask.

Worked for me after many failed tensorflow saving/loading attempts.

(thanks to shafy @github)
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2397#issuecomment-338659190

for me, it looks like this, at the bottom of my flask app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

also see 
[Loading a huge Keras Model into a Flask App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822458/loading-a-huge-keras-model-into-a-flask-app/47777876#47777876)